# Apache Configure CORS Headers for Whitelist Routes

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cors, apache2.4

I'm trying to allow calls made to "/api/whateverEndpoint", while keeping CORS strict for all other calls.

I've come across this link [Whitelisted CORS using Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26811599/whitelisted-cors-using-apache) which gives the solution for origin filtering:

```
# e.g. origin = https://host-b.local
SetEnvIfNoCase Origin "https://host-b.local" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
```

But i need to adapt this to filter based on the request uri.

Any idea is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you just need to set a variable based on a match against `Request_URI`, then use that; like this:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/api/whateverEndpoint" IsAllowedEndpoint
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IsAllowedEndpoint
```